# basicnetwork.performrequest exception on fetching data from a GET API android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I need to fetch data in android from the in the data array of the following api

```
http://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/MULTPL/SP500_REAL_PRICE_MONTH.json?start_date=1915-01-01&api_key=UPqWzYxopvhzdoRt5jTS
```

I tried both JSONObject request and string request

```
JsonObjectRequest obreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url.URL_SNP_2,
           // The third parameter Listener overrides the method onResponse() and passes
           //JSONObject as a parameter
           new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

               // Takes the response from the JSON request
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   Log.d("Response", "Getting CAB Response: " + response.toString());

                   Toast.makeText(Fragment_CAB_SNP_2.this.getActivity(), "response:" + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
                   // Try and catch are included to handle any errors due to JSON

           },
           // The final parameter overrides the method onErrorResponse() and passes VolleyError
           //as a parameter
           new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   Log.e("Volley", "Error");
               }
           }
   );
   // Adds the JSON object request "obreq" to the request queue
   requestQueue.add(obreq);
```

but it gives following exception

```
E/Volley: [35011] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Request at http://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/MULTPL/SP500_REAL_PRICE_MONTH.json?start_date=1915-01-01&api_key=UPqWzYxopvhzdoRt5jTS has been redirected to https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/MULTPL/SP500_REAL_PRICE_MONTH.json?start_date=1915-01-01&api_key=UPqWzYxopvhzdoRt5jTS
05-11 23:02:25.134 27238-27238/com. E/Volley: Error
```

no response is fetched.pls help me

Answer (score 0):

First check for the response data in the VolleyError and parse it your self.
see what error it is throwing.

Volley throws a ServerError exception that contains the raw network response.

So you can do something similar to this in your error listener:

```
/* import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser; */
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    // As of f605da3 the following should work
    NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
    if (error instanceof ServerError && response != null) {
        try {
            String res = new String(response.data,
                       HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));
            // Now you can use any deserializer to make sense of data
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // Couldn't properly decode data to string
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e2) {
            // returned data is not JSONObject?
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still no response.can u pls hit the above api once and try to get response?

Comment: The issue was with the api and not with the code.Now it is solved.Thanks:)